How to maintain query params when redirecting in Angular RoutingModule with redirectTo?
Summary
I want to redirect in my Angular RoutingModule from one path to another while maintaining the query params. However, when the redirect completes, the query params are not present anymore.
The use case here is that our UIs offering deep links are supposed to have the deep links start with a certain path: /views. However, the displayed components belong to separate Angular modules, therefore I want to redirect to the pages in the respective modules.
Example



Deep link
should redirect to
but redirects to




/views/createNewFoo?type=a&date=2024-01-01
/foo/create?type=a&date=2024-01-01
/foo/create



Route Config
{
  path: 'views',
  pathMatch: 'prefix',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'createNewFoo',
      redirectTo: '/foo/create'
    }
  ]
}


Angular >=18
I solved it with a RedirectFunction:
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RedirectFunction } from '@angular/router';

export const redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams =
    (redirectToUrl: string): RedirectFunction =>
    ({ queryParams }) =>
        Object.keys(queryParams).length ? `${redirectToUrl}?${new HttpParams({ fromObject: queryParams }).toString()}` : redirectToUrl;

Then the route config:
{
  path: viewsPath,
  pathMatch: 'prefix',
  children: [
    {
      path: createEvvNoticeViewPath,
      redirectTo: redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams('/foo/create'),
    }
  ]
}

Jest test for the RedirectFunction:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RedirectFunction } from '@angular/router';
import { redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams } from './redirect-while-keeping-query-params';

const redirectToUrl = '/foo/create';

describe('redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams', () => {
    const executeRedirectFn: RedirectFunction = (...guardParameters) =>
        TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams(redirectToUrl)(...guardParameters));

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

    it('should be created', () => expect(executeRedirectFn).toBeTruthy());

    it('should redirect to the given route', () => {
        // Arrange
        const route = { queryParams: { key1: 'value', key2: 123 } } as Partial<ActivatedRouteSnapshot> as ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

        // Act
        const redirectRoute = executeRedirectFn(route);

        // Assert
        expect(redirectRoute).toBe(`${redirectToUrl}?key1=value&key2=123`);
    });
});

Angular <18
I solved it with a CanActivateFn:
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

export const redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams =
    (redirectTo: string): CanActivateFn =>
    route =>
        from(inject(Router).navigate([redirectTo], { queryParams: route.queryParams }));

Then the route config:
{
  path: 'views',
  pathMatch: 'prefix',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'createNewFoo',
      canActivate: [redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams('/foo/create')],
      children: []
    }
  ]
}

Jest test for the CanActivateFn:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivateFn, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams } from './redirect-while-keeping-query-params';

const redirectTo = '/foo/create';

describe('redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams', () => {
    const executeGuard: CanActivateFn = (...guardParameters) =>
        TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => redirectWhileKeepingQueryParams(redirectTo)(...guardParameters));

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

    it('should be created', () => expect(executeGuard).toBeTruthy());

    it('should redirect to the given route', () => {
        // Arrange
        const navigateSpy = jest.spyOn(TestBed.inject(Router), 'navigate');
        const route = { queryParams: { key1: 'value', key2: 123 } } as Partial<ActivatedRouteSnapshot> as ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
        const state = {} as RouterStateSnapshot;

        // Act
        executeGuard(route, state);

        // Assert
        expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([redirectTo], { queryParams: route.queryParams });
    });
});


Woo, that CanActivate solution is a hack and a half haha. Spot on with the redirect function. +1
